# how to represent void* return from emscripten/webassembly call

Tags: javascript, node.js, webassembly, emscripten

I have a function exported to web asembly like this

```
void* EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE InitializeLibrary(){
    SomeStruct s;
    s.k = 18;
    s.t = 21;
    return (void*)&s;
}
```

and functions uses the returned structure/pointer from the above on the suceeding calls as an SDK/API. For the same of sample Il just create a simple function like so

```
int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE Add(void* b){
    SomeStruct* bg = (SomeStruct*)b;
    return bg->k + bg->t;
}
```

Question, using Module.ccall or cwrap, how to specify the function return and/or the function parameters is a void*?

Thanks in advance.

Post edit, perhaps this is not just a void* but returns a structure pointer, and pass it back to functions as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript type of C pointer is number.

```
var arg = Module.ccall('InitializeLibrary', 'number',[]);
var result = Module.ccall('Add', 'number', ['number'], [arg]);
console.log({arg, result});
```

And returning a pointer to local variable is invalid.

```
void* EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE InitializeLibrary(){
  SomeStruct* s = malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct));
  s->k = 18;
  s->t = 21;
  return (void*)s;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. If I have a function pointer like: "void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE (*myfunctionpointer)(const char *)" how do I use cwrap to call it? "var myfunction = Module.cwrap("myfunctionpointer", number, ["string"])", and then simply do "myfunction()"?

Comment: A function pointer is another topic. Search other QA or create new question.